# populating admin user credential in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my app to Heroku. I lost all data in my database including admin user credential, which I need to initially log into my app to be able to use the app.

How do i populate or push those admin user credential in the Heroku's database? I am not worried about other data since they are all silly test data.

Dev Env-

Rails 4.0.0
SQLite3

Your help will be appreciated a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the console on the heroku server. Find your way to your project's directory in your terminal and then type `heroku run console`. You'll have an irb console where you can simple create an admin with proper credentials.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly now. I am able to create admin user through console and able to log into site.:)